# Ansible playbook block ALL IP exclude one or more IP

Tags: module, ansible, iptables

I'm starting to use Ansible to develop a playbook that perform some actions on the system iptables. 
I have a server and I want to block ALL IP except one or more IP.

I really don't know how to write the iptables rules using the ansible modules. I need to:

1. Drop all incoming traffic
   (iptables -P INPUT DROP)
2. Drop all incoming traffic (iptables -P INPUT DROP)
3. Drop all forwarded traffic (iptables -P FORWARD DROP)
4. Allow all outgoing traffic (iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT)
5. iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s ipaddress --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

So far, I've created this Playbook:

```
---

  - hosts: localhost
    remote_user: sysadmin
    become: true

    vars:
      host_name: localhost

    tasks:

  # Drop all incoming traffic
  # iptables -P INPUT DROP
     - iptables:
         chain: INPUT
         protocol: all
         jump: DROP
       become: yes


  # Drop all forwarded traffic
  # iptables -P FORWARD DROP
     - iptables:
         chain: FORWARD
         source: all
         jump: DROP
       become: yes

  # Allow all outgoing traffic
  #iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
     - iptables:
         chain: OUTPUT
         source: all
         jump: ACCEPT
       become: yes

  # Allow all outgoing traffic
  # iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx/32 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
     - iptables:
         action: append
         chain: INPUT
         protocol: tcp
         source: ip_address
         destination_port: 22
         jump: ACCEPT
       become: yes
```

Comment: I think you need to change the task order, because first you need to allow the ips that you want and then drop all, otherwise it will drop everything and will not respect your allow rules.

Comment: I think you need to change the task order, because first you need to allow the ips that you want and then drop all, otherwise it will drop everything and will not respect your allow rules.

Comment: Even if I use the -append option?

Answer (score 2):

I solved taking different steps:

1. iptables -A INPUT -s 2.228.104.210 -j ACCEPT
2. iptables -A OUTPUT -d 2.228.104.210 -j ACCEPT
3. iptables -P INPUT DROP
4. iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

And the working playbook:

```
---

  - hosts: localhost
    remote_user: sysadmin
    become: true

    vars:
      host_name: localhost

    tasks:

     - iptables:
         chain: INPUT
         source: 192.168.1.1
         jump: ACCEPT
       become: yes


     - iptables:
         chain: OUTPUT
         destination: 192.168.1.1
         jump: ACCEPT
       become: yes


     - iptables:
         chain: INPUT
         policy: DROP
       become: yes


     - iptables:
         chain: OUTPUT
         policy: DROP
       become: yes
```